# DJCelery to Celery + Django 1.8 to 1.10 = Postgres Connection Issues

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery, django-celery

I've been trying to debug an issue whereby my application is getting "OperationalError: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections" using postgres 9.4 and Django 1.10.

As part of the switch from 1.8 to 1.10 we began using plain ol' celery rather than dj-celery for our task scheduling.

[Threaded Django task doesn't automatically handle transactions or db connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303654/threaded-django-task-doesnt-automatically-handle-transactions-or-db-connections)
The above SO question has me thinking that the issue might be that our celery tasks are keeping their connections open. I could see how switching from dj-celery to celery could impact our django integration.

I've increased the maximum number of connections from 100 to 500 (well within our hardware's memory capability) as a bandaid, but I need this connection count to go down. For now, the connection count seems to have stabilized at 180 and isn't going up further, but I'm worried about not being able to throw more memory at the problem.

While I suspect celery, it could be another part of my app code that is failing to close these connections. Is there a way for me to see in Postgres which connections are staying open? The only query I've been running so far has been `SELECT numbackends FROM pg_stat_database;` but that only tells me that I have a certain number of connections open. I'd adore a traceback or query plan for what made the connections open at a given time.

Comment: How about `netstat -pn|grep 5432`?

Comment: How many celery workers/processes are running? How does that compare against the number of open connections that database is reporting?